# best way to store a list of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

What would be the best way to store and read a really long string, with each entry is an index for another array?

Right now I have this

```
String indices="1,4,6,19,22,54,....."
```

The string has up to hundred of thousand entries, so I think maybe I could use a data structure like Linked List. Does anyone know if it would be faster to use one?

Comment: Faster for what purpose? For serializing, a `String` is going to be faster than anything else. However, for access, it is likely to be very slow compared to a list of some kind.

Comment: if they are all index pointing to something else you could use a hashmap<String, Object>

Comment: ArrayList is faster than LinkedList and takes less memory.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart not necessarily, `ArrayList`s require periodical increase in capacity to handle multiple insertions. Quote from the docs : "An application can increase the capacity of an ArrayList instance before adding a large number of elements using the ensureCapacity operation. This may reduce the amount of incremental reallocation."

Comment: @mbatchkarov Yes, I was assuming that the list was initialized such that subsequent reallocation would be kept to a minimum.

Comment: Ted, I'm actually reading this list in from a file, but not sure if I should use a string. Right now I am using a StringBuilder to append the entries. Then I need to iterate the list, and compress them. If I use a Linked List I won't have to split the string.

Comment: Valek, you are right subsequent reallocation is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("1");
list.add("2");
```

you need to declare arraylist of type string.Then add to it.

Comment: Right, but is using this faster than one single string and split into hundred of thousand entries? Basically I need to iterate through the entire string.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on what you'll do with the string (the indices) and the corresponding arrays. Also, it will depend on how you're gonna access them.

I'd suggest you first read an overview about the data structures implemented in java, specially in the [Collections Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html).

We could give some suggestions, but you'd have to provide us more information, specially those I mentioned in the beginning (what you want, how this data will be stored and accessed, and so on).

For example, if you need to have a fast access to the indexed data, maybe a string isn't even the best approach. Maybe a map would be better. The indexes could be the keys and the indexed arrays could be the values of the map, for example. But this is just a void example, I strongly suggest you give us more information.

Comment: I understand Linked List and Array List but not sure If i should use them. I need to traverse the string from beginning to end basically.

Answer (score 1):

I really like using the ArrayList class, which if your comfortable using arrays, ArrayList or any member of the Collections Framework. Would work really well. For what your trying to do.

```
ArrayList<String> indices = new ArrayList<String>();
indices.add("");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have similar hunch in my mind , in which I want to like 1k number of strings and parse them (searching purpose to know it contain item or not).

Hence I found instead of using java collection framework - **map or set or list**

**if I store data simply in array and start parsing data using for-loop, it is faster.**

You visit this link and see actual output which we calculated in micro seconds.

https://www.programcreek.com/2014/04/check-if-array-contains-a-value-java/

So using simple brute force is winner in case of unsorted array
 (normally we have).

But `arrays.BinarySearch()` is winner if array is sorted.